# How to add arguments to a script

Tags: shell-script, arguments

I would like to know how to add arguments to commands.

I would like it to be somewhat like this:

```
$ arg --test
```

'arg' would be the main command and '--test' would be the argument.

Comment: Would `arg` in your example be a shell script, C code, Python, or something else?

Comment: Do you already know how to make `arg` so it can be called as in your example (but without `--test`)?

Comment: Don't think that's necessarily a duplicate as it doesn't refer to `getopt` and friends to parse double-dash options.

Comment: As is OP is basically just asking what a positional parameter is.  If the question is modified to be more specific something like getopts could be useful.

Comment: +1 for *"I won't just copy and paste the code you are supplying me with."*

Answer (score 0):

For numbered arguments between `0` and `9` where `x` is the specific numbered argument, use this notation:

```
$x
```

For numbered arguments above that where `x` is the specific numbered argument, use this notation:

```
${x}
```

For a list of all arguments, use this:

```
${@}
```

Or this:

```
${*}
```

Note that when double-quoted, `${*}` expands all arguments space-separated (usually, technically it's the first character of the variable `$IFS` (internal field separator)) into one string. `${@}` expands into multiple strings when double-quoted.

Bracketing is not necessary when using `${@}` or `${*}`.

Answer (score -1):

This may be a duplicate to questions answered. However, please find a possible solution to your request as a very basic shell script below.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in ${@} ; do
    case ${i} in
        --test)     echo "test option found"
                    ;;
        *)          echo "Usage: $0 [--test]"
                    exit 1
    esac
done
echo "$0 finished."
```

You may learn something more if you play around with options to this shell script on the command line.  This may add to the first answer by [JL2210](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/327020/jl2210) quite appropriately.

N.B. The line `echo "Usage: $0 [--test]"` aims to offer some help message and makes use of the convention to indicate optional arguments in square brackets.

Hope this helps.